# Hash keys and values

Tags: ruby

I would like to know if you have any more practical way of working with keys, value in ruby.

I had to improvise to be able to access and print the keys `Rafael` and `Roberto` and at the same time print their keys and values

My code:

```
arr = Hash.new
arr["Rafael"] = []
arr["Roberto"] = []

listaProdutos = [
    "banana",
    "uva",
    "biscoito"
]

listaProdutos.each{ |i|
    arr["Rafael"] << {"Produto": i, "Quantidade": rand(1..9)}
    arr["Roberto"] << {"Produto": i, "Quantidade": rand(1..9)}
}

arr.each{ |k,lista|
    (0..arr.count).each do |i|
        puts "#{k} vai comprar #{arr[k][i][:Quantidade]} unidades de #{arr[k][i][:Produto]}"
    end
}
```

Comment: `arr = Hash.new`. arr is an unfortunate variable name.

Comment: I think a more specific context to your real situation might be helpful, this is just a rube goldeberg.

Comment: @steenslag, in Portuguese "arr" means "hash". You might say, for example, "arr batatas marrons", for "hash brown potatoes".

Comment: You should use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`. And it's usually a good idea to keep class names, method names, and variable names in English.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh that is enlightening.  I use `arr` for arrays routinely, probably confusing all Portuguese speakers.

Comment: @steenslag, worse yet, the Portuguese word for "array" is "hash".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
arr.each{ |k,lista|
    (0..arr.count).each do |i|
        puts "#{k} vai comprar #{arr[k][i][:Quantidade]} unidades de #{arr[k][i][:Produto]}"
    end
}
```

Can we rewritten as:

```
arr.each do |k, lista|
  lista.each do |obj|
    puts "#{k} vai comprar #{obj[:Quantidade]} unidades de #{obj[:Produto]}"
  end
end
```